# Group Policy Error/DC Issues

Tags: group-policy, domain-controller, netlogon, sysvol

We've got an issue in our domain environment with 2 of our On-Prem DCs (including primary DC) missing content in the SYSVOL folder.

[Current Setup with missing folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjPvq.jpg)

[Correct Domain Folder Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBLKR.jpg)

Our environment currently has 4 DCs, 3 On-Prem long-serving ones and a new Azure DC and we have backups for all of them.

It looks like the both of the DCs had dirty power cycles and they've also lost the shares for NETLOGON and SYSVOL.

[Missing Shares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbPnv.jpg)

This in turn has been causing issues with Active Directory Web Services as we can no longer run any of the ad commands via powershell and group policies are not editable even though we can still see them in GPMC.

[ADWS Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmPGo.jpg)

[Group Policy Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cmna.jpg)

One of our other DCs looks like it's ok with the folders being in the right place and the shares are still present.

I've had a check at the DFSR service and that hasn't reported any errors.

I confirmed the same with repladmin and it's showing successful replications for all 4 of the DCs with 0 failures.

Event viewer is not logging any of the normal errors indicating any issues with AD but we can see that the SYSVOL data is missing.

Anyone got any idea how to proceed with this? Restore the missing folders to a separate location, disable Replication on all the DCs, copy the folders back to their correct location, then authoritatively trigger a new replication from the primary DC or trigger the replication from the DC that's still up and running?

What about the missing shares for NETLOGON and SYSVOL on the other DCs?

I'm hoping we don't have to rebuild the SYSVOL tree.

Comment: `...disable Replication on all the DCs, copy the folders back to their correct location,...`. God no why would you do that? There's a procedure for authoritatively replicating SYSVOL, use that, it's what it's for.